# Can not open downloaded PDF files

Tags: file, python-2.7, pdf, download, python-requests

I'm trying to download needed PDFs related to a researcher.

But the downloaded PDFs can't be opened, saying that the files may be damaged or in wrong format. While another URL used in test resulted in normal PDF files. Do you have any suggestion?

```
 import requests  
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  


 def download_file(url, index):  
     local_filename = index+"-"+url.split('/')[-1]  
     # NOTE the stream=True parameter  
     r = requests.get(url, stream=True)  
     with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:  
         for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):  
             if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks  
                 f.write(chunk)  
                 f.flush()  
     return local_filename  


 # For Test:   http://ww0.java4.datastructures.net/handouts/
 # Can't open: http://flyingv.ucsd.edu/smoura/publications.html

 root_link="http://ecal.berkeley.edu/publications.html#journals"

 r=requests.get(root_link)  
 if r.status_code==200:  
     soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)  
     # print soup.prettify()  
     index=1  
     for link in soup.find_all('a'):  
         new_link=root_link+link.get('href')
         if new_link.endswith(".pdf"):  
             file_path=download_file(new_link,str(index))  
             print "downloading:"+new_link+" -> "+file_path  
             index+=1  
     print "all download finished"  
 else:  
     print "errors occur."
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at the file contents yet?

Comment: Actually, I checked the downloading links, they are wrong directory. Now I fixed this question, thanks!
But fixing the directory means this program cannot be used generally, which is a problem I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a comment saying:

> `# Can't open: http://flyingv.ucsd.edu/smoura/publications.html`

Looks like what you can't open is a HTML file. So no wonder that a PDF reader will complain about it...

For any real PDF link that I had a problem with I would proceed as follows:

1. Download file with a different method (`wget`, `curl`, a browser, ...).

   - Can you download it even? Or is there some password hoop to be jumped through?
   - Is the download fast + complete?
2. Does it then open in a PDF viewer?

   - If so, compare to the file your script downloaded.

     - What are the differences?
     - Could they be caused by your script?
     - Are there no differences within the first few hundred lines, but differences later? End of the file being a bunch of nul-bytes? Then your download didn't complete...
   - If not so, still compare the differences. If there are none, your script is not at fault. The PDF may *really* be corrupted...
3. What does it look like, when opened in a text editor?

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm trying to download all the linked pdf files in this root_link page.